# Is it possible to name columns in pandas DataFrame using name from list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with 2506 items. I want to create df that name each column how an each item of this list

```
data=['some_values_that_i_need_to_save']
list=['some_values']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': data[0::11],
    'Seller': data[1::11],
    'SellerId': data[2::11],
    'warehouse': data[3::11],
    'categoryID': data[4::11],
    'description': data[5::11],
    'url': data[6::11],
    'price': data[7::11],
    'currency': data[8::11],
    'img': data[9::11],
    'barcode': data[10::11],

    for i in range(len(list)):
      if i>10:
         f'{list[i]}': data[i::2517],
})
data.to_csv('qwe.csv')
```

I know that is incorrect how I wrote here, but I don't have an idea how to solve this
Thank you

Comment: 'Name': data[0::11], here and next slices are [0::2517]

Comment: please provide a real example and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want but if you have two lists one providing the data and one the names:

```
names = ['Name','Seller','SellerId']
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

You can create a DataFrame from them using the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).T, columns=names)
```

which gives:

```
   Name Seller  SellerId
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```